# How to create a table with random data in Ember.Js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, html-table

I want to create a random table data but only cells makes random the rows always repeated. Here is my code:

component/ember-app..js

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  willRender: function() {
    var tableRows = [];
    var value = ['|', '-'];
    var numRows = 20;
    var numCells = 20;
    for (var row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) {
      for (var cell = 1; cell <= numCells; cell++) {
        tableRows[row] = value[Math.round(Math.random())];
      }
    }

    this.set('rows', {
      'tableRows': tableRows,
    });

  }
});
```

And templates/components/ember-app.hbs

```
  <table>
{{#each-in rows as |table tableRow|}}
{{#each tableRow}}
  <tr>
      {{#each tableRow as |tableRows|}}
      <td><button id="button_id"{{action "changeValue"}} value="{{tableRows}}">{{tableRows}}</button></td>
      {{/each}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
  {{/each-in}}
</table>
```

Comment: Is this path `templates/ember-app.hbs` correct? i believe it would be `templates/components/ember-app.hbs` . you can use init hook to init data. what is your question exactly ?. is your code is not working ?.

Comment: I already correct the patch. No, my code is working,but data is not random in rows only in cells

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating different cells values for each row,

Component.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  willRender: function() {
    var tableRows = [];
    var value = ['|', '-'];
    var numRows = 20;
    var numCells = 20;
    for (var row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) {
      var cellArr = []
      for (var cell = 1; cell <= numCells; cell++) {
        console.log('Math.round(Math.random()) ',Math.round(Math.random()));
        cellArr[cell] = value[Math.round(Math.random())];
      }
      tableRows[row]=cellArr;
    }

    this.set('rows', {
      'tableRows': tableRows,
    });

  }
});
```

in component hbs,

```
<table>
{{#each-in rows as |table tableRow|}}
{{log 'tableRow ' tableRow ' table ' table}}
{{#each tableRow as |singleRow|}}
  <tr>
      {{#each singleRow as |tableRows|}}
      <td><button id="button_id"{{action "changeValue"}} value="{{tableRows}}">{{tableRows}}</button></td>
      {{/each}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
  {{/each-in}}
</table>
{{yield}}
```

I would suggest you consider, `Ember.Object` and use init hook to `init` data.
[ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d2547f70b099f261ee594461cc264b36?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: another request I want to check if all cells are the same alert("smth"); How can I do that: I wrote a function that changes data: Here is code.

Comment: `actions: {
    changeValue: function() {
      this.$().on('click', '.cellValue', function(event) {
        if ($(this).text() == '|') {
          $(this).text('-');
        } else if ($(this).text() == '-') {
          $(this).text('|');
        } else {

        }
      });
    }
  }`